# R gsub partial replacement wildcards

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I hope this is sufficiently different related, prior posts to justify its own thread; unfortunately, they were unhelpful to me. I think my interest in partial replacement, *plus* use of a wildcard is thus far unique, but apologies if I simply haven't searched or read carefully enough!

Suppose I have the following string:

```
str <- c("FOO_1", "FOO_2", "BAR_1", "BAR_2")
```

I'd like to replace the `1` at the end of `FOO_1` with something else, say `A`. I attempted to do so with both

```
gsub("[^F.*](1)$", "\\_A", str)
```

and

```
gsub("^F.*(1)$", "\\_BLAH", str)
```

but clearly neither of them worked to replace *only* `1`, leaving the rest of `FOO_` intact, while also not altering `BAR_1`. I have a dumb solution to the problem that simply involves a line of `grep()` and a line of `gsub()`, but I will hate myself if that's what I settle on.

Comment: What is the rule here? Just replace `_1` at the end of the string? `sub("_1$", "_A", x)`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/mKj7Uh) - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; I _only_ want to replace variables _starting_ with `FOO` and _ending_ with `1`. So, for instance, if the approach changes `BAR_1` to `BAR_A`, that is a failure.

I was just trying to provide a minimal working example, but in the actual case, there are several permutations of the same variable. E.g., `FOO_A_1`, `FOO_B_1`, and so on; I'd like to capture all `^FOO.*1$` (sorry if this is stated incorrectly).

Comment: [`sub("^(FOO.*)_1$", "\\1_A", str)`](https://ideone.com/Nxqsi9)?

Comment: Does this need to scale? Are you only looking to replace `FOO_1` with `FOO_A`?

Comment: Just tested and @WiktorStribiżew's answer appears sufficient for my purposes. Thanks so much! Apologies for the disturbance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done and done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only want to replace variables *starting* with `FOO` and *ending* with `1`

Capture `FOO` and everything after it into Group 1 and just match `_1` at the end of the string. Then, in the replacement pattern, use a replacement backreference to the Group1  value:

```
str <- c("FOO_1", "FOO_2", "BAR_1", "BAR_2")
sub("^(FOO.*)_1$", "\\1_A", str)
## => [1] "FOO_A" "FOO_2" "BAR_1" "BAR_2"
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/Nxqsi9)

If any digit amount at the end of the string must be matched, replace `1` with `\\d+`.

**Details**

- `^` - string start
- `(FOO.*)` - `FOO` substring and then any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `_1` - a `_1` substring  (if you replace `1` with `\\d+`, it will match 1 or more digits)
- `$` - end of string.